# Can't zoom to see the whole map in OL3

Tags: mapserver, openlayers

I have a special map. Its rather a schema not a common world map. Not very high but it is very long. Now when I display the map, I see a part of the schema at zoom level 0 (I additionally set it programatically usin setZoom(0)) also the zoom slider is all the way down and with -(minus) button I cannot zoom out more to see the whole schema.

I set the map like this:

```
var TSKmap = new MyMap({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      zoom: 1,
      center: [0,0],
      projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326')
    })
});
```

Add WMS layer using TileWMS source with the following parameters

```
BBOX    =-90,-180,270,180
CRS     = EPSG:4326
FORMAT  = image/png
HEIGHT  = 256
LAYERS  = lyr1,lyr2,lyr1_labels,common_labels
REQUEST = GetMap
SERVICE = WMS
TRANSPARENT = true
VERSION = 1.3.0
WIDTH = 256
idk   = 17
idp   = 101
map   = schemas/schema1.map
version = 20.3
```

The l1 layer is setup in the `schemas/schema1.map` like this:

```
LAYER
NAME "..."
METADATA
  "wms_title"          "..."
  "wms_abstract"       "..."
  "wms_keywordlist"    "..."
  "wms_extent"         "-5000 -2000 50000 4000"      
  "wms_enable_request" "*"
  "wms_include_items"  "all"      

  "wfs_typename"       "..."
  "wfs_version"        "1.1.0"
  "wfs_title"          "..."
  "wfs_abstract"       "..."
  "wfs_keywordlist"    "..."
  "gml_include_items"  "all"
  "gml_featureid"      "featid"
  "wfs_enable_request" "*"
END
```

Interesting information from mapfile:

```
MAP
  NAME "TSK_WMS_WFS"
  DEBUG 5   
  SIZE 1020 690  
  EXTENT -5000 -2000 50000 4000       
  UNITS METERS
  FONTSET etc/fonts.txt
  MAXSIZE 4096  

  WEB
    IMAGEPATH "tmp/" 
    IMAGEURL "tmp/"
    METADATA
      ...
      "wms_srs"                           "EPSG:4326"
      "wms_encoding"                      "UTF-8"
      "wms_bbox_extended"                 "true"
      "wms_extent"                        "-5000 -2000 50000 4000"
      "wms_server_version"                "1.3.0"      
      "wms_enable_request"                "*"

      "wms_feature_info_mime_type"        "text/html"   
      "wms_format"                        "image/png"              

      "wfs_srs"                           "EPSG:4326"
      "wfs_enable_request"                "*"
      "wfs_encoding"                      "UTF-8"
      "wfs_extent"                        "-5000 -2000 50000 4000"         
      "wfs_version"                       "1.1.0" 

    END 
  END 

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  ...
```

Any Ideas how to set the view so, that I shoul see the whole schema when I zoom to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to find out the extent of data in projection of data (EPSG: 4326 in my case) and set it for the projection:

```
ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').setExtent([148, -8, 17558, 178])
```